# What's the difference between vector<vector<int>> vec and vector<vector<int>> vec(n)?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, segmentation-fault, stdvector

I was trying to access vector elements today, so when I used `vector<vector<int>> vec` and then added elements to it. I was able to access those elements like `vec[1][2]`.

But when I use `vector<vector<int>> vec(n)` and then added elements, I was not able to access the elements using `vec[1][2]`. I keep getting a segmentation error. Does anyone know what am I missing here?

I am adding the elements to the vector through with the help of the below code snippet.

```
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<vector<int>> vh;
int size, input;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    vector<int> temp;
    cin >> size;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        cin >> input;
        temp.push_back(input);
    }
    vh.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: [A decent `std::vector` constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) should be helpful.

Comment: And besides, either attempt to use the vectors seems to be leading to *undefined behavior* as you go out of bounds. Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mre].

Comment: Create a [mcve], please.  The issue is likely with how you are "adding elements" but we can't guess how you are doing that.

Comment: You've created an empty vector in the first case, but a vector of `n` empty vectors in the second case. In the first case any access with the first `[]` operator results in undefined behaviour (which can include a segfault); in the second case you still need to add at least 3 elements to the second vector to get non-undefined behaviour when using `vec[1][2]` (assuming `n >=2`)

Comment: Are you following some kind of tutorial on how to use `std::vector`?

Comment: @NateEldredge I have added the way by which I am adding elements to the 2D vector. It works here. When I use `vh(n)` it does not work. That's about the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can ***guess*** what the problems is...

When you use the constructor with an argument:

```
vector<vector<int>> vh(n);
```

you create a vector with the size `n`, it means it will already have `n` elements, where each element will be a default-constructed `vector<int>`. Which means that each vector will be *empty*.

Then you *push back* a new vector:

```
vh.push_back(temp);
```

This will *increase* the size of the vector. After one such `push_back` call the size of `vh` will be `n + 1`. The new vector you add will be at index `n`, i.e. `vh[n]` is the new vector.

If you set the size when you define the vector, then you need to use indexing and assignment to set the sub-vectors:

```
vh[i] = temp;
```

---

To summarize:

- Either you create an empty vector and push back new elements:

  ```
  vector<vector<int>> vh;
  ```

  and

  ```
  vh.push_back(temp);
  ```
- Or you create a vector with a size, and use indexing and assignment:

  ```
  vector<vector<int>> vh(n);
  ```

  and

  ```
  v[i] = temp;
  ```

Don't mix these ways.

---

Now when you got your current code working (hopefully) and understand how these things work a little better, it's time to show a way how to do your code in a more "C++-ish" way... :)

```
// The first part is much like your current code
size_t n;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vh(n);

// Now iterate over all the elements in the vector
for (auto& v : vh)
{
    // Get the size of the current sub-vector
    size_t size;
    std::cin >> size;

    // Create the vector with size elements
    v = std::vector<int>(size);

    // Read size integers into the vector
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), size, begin(v));
}
```

Comment: Maybe add how to directly initialize a 2D array with elements: `vector<vector<int> >(n, vector<int>(m, 0));`

Comment: @Aziuth That's not really the same. In the OP's code the sub-vectors can all be of different size.